# iOS Simulator keeps quitting unexpectedly after system updates - cannot launch Simulator.app

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, simulator

Until two days ago, Xcode and simulators were working perfectly fine. I turned the computer off and some software updates got installed, including macOS Catalina). I am now unable to launch Simulator. It's for any device, it simply doesn't open the application. All I see is the following:

[simulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtdLO.png)

I've also noticed that the following two processors keep themselves alive no matter how many times I quit them or kill them from command line:

[processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxm43.png)

I found this similar post, but it's old and I don't have a DeviceTypes folder as stated.
https://shirome9.wordpress.com/2016/11/27/xcode-quit-unexpectedly/

I have tried different approaches, including:

- Deleting DerivedData folder
- Deleting /Library/Developer/Xcode folder
- Updating Xcode to 11.1
- Usinng Xcode 10.3, where the command line tools are actually incompatible with Catalina OS.
- Reinstalling Xcode, restarting my machine at every step of the deletion and reinstallation
- Deleting CoreSimulator folder
- The following commands in terminal:

`sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`

`sudo killall -10 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`

`xcrun simctl erase all`

`fastlane snapshot reset_simulators`

Here's a part of the crash report:

```
Process:               Simulator [2411]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
Identifier:            com.apple.iphonesimulator
Version:               11.1 (912.1)
Build Info:            Indigo-912001000000000~187
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Simulator [2411]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-10-20 11:58:37.080 -0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15 (19A602)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y906)
Anonymous UUID:        22EA5B9E-426E-8952-358B-B710A2F7B37E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1D8E834A-E0DC-4EFB-9E9F-591E94D88283

Time Awake Since Boot: 13000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007000006a8fd8
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Bus error: 10
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process:   exc handler [2411]

VM Regions Near 0x7000006a8fd8:
    __LINKEDIT             000000010e9e0000-000000010ea17000 [  220K] r--/r-- SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
--> STACK GUARD            00007000006a8000-00007000006a9000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 1
    Stack                  00007000006a9000-000070000072b000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 1

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6e7de9f6 __ulock_wait + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6e643ca6 _dlock_wait + 44
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6e643b35 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 36
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6e653f51 _dispatch_apply_invoke_and_wait + 264
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6e653a39 dispatch_apply_f + 761
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff374db27f __104-[CFPrefsSearchListSource synchronouslySendDaemonMessage:andAgentMessage:andDirectMessage:replyHandler:]_block_invoke.119 + 97
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3740d1dd CFPREFERENCES_IS_WAITING_FOR_SYSTEM_AND_USER_CFPREFSDS + 74
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff374db037 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource synchronouslySendDaemonMessage:andAgentMessage:andDirectMessage:replyHandler:] + 172
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff37389aa3 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_generationCountFromListOfSources:count:] + 215
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff37389500 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_getDictionary:] + 360
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff37389124 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 152
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3738906c -[CFPrefsSource copyValueForKey:] + 47
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3738902a __76-[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:]_block_invoke + 32
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3737284c __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 381
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3737247f -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 364
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3737220e -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 145
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff37371eb4 _CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainerAndConfiguration + 101
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff39a313e7 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) init] + 1367
18  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff39a39706 +[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) standardUserDefaults] + 66
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff345a2014 +[NSApplication initialize] + 87
20  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff6d336ca5 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 17
21  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff6d3375d6 initializeNonMetaClass + 638
22  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff6d3373a4 initializeNonMetaClass + 76
23  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff6d337b15 initializeAndMaybeRelock(objc_class*, objc_object*, mutex_tt<false>&, bool) + 214
24  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff6d329c5c lookUpImpOrForward + 969
25  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff6d329419 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 73
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff345a1ce2 NSApplicationMain + 366
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6e693405 start + 1

Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3736144a CFDictionaryGetValue + 75
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3738c419 __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 93
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3738db6c __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 6064
```

Any help is highly appreciated. I am losing serious time due to this issue.

Comment: Does the crash report shed any light on the issue? What happens if you launch Xcode in another user account?

Comment: Yes, please paste the actual crash report instead of showing the dialog.

Comment: I have attached part of the crash report (it's too long to attach it entirely, otherwise I'll upload it apart). The process crashing is indeed Simulator.app. I've looked up the exception code but none of the errors relates to mine, they are mostly for real devices.